# How to leave only distinct rows in the table. Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to delete all duplicate in **40kk** of rows. I've got table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (
PRIMARY KEY (account_id, match_id, id),
id bigserial,
account_id bigint,
match_id bigint,
win boolean,
... );
```

I've tried this query but after 1h of executing I've gave up on waiting.

```
DELETE FROM players WHERE players.id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (match_id, account_id) * 
  FROM players) as X);
```

Is there any other solution to delete duplicates in more optimazed way?

UPD: I need to do it just once cause I didn't handle the duplicates at the start

Comment: There is a primary key and the command you tried to execute is not meant to delete duplicates. Please give some example with data because there is discrepancy between the question and your intention.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc5aba8597485a20500fa1e3d6bb8009 
here is detailed example what I want to achive

Comment: Does it matter the order of id here? Because you used "30" as an id for (165, 617348) pair.

Comment: Your example will delete the duplicates (which aren't fully duplicates) in a non-deterministic fashion.  Do you really not care which row remains?

Comment: Questions about performance require you to include the execution plan. Please post it.

Comment: What does "40kk" mean?

Comment: Order does not matter in this case. 40kk means 40millions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database systems do not like delete and update processes. If you have permission to control transactions on this table and if you do not care which id will be deleted you can follow this approach.

1.Create a table with unique values.

2.Switch the table names.

```
create  table players_tmp as select match_id, account_id, win, id from (select match_id, account_id, win, id,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY match_id, account_id ORDER BY id) as rn
from players) r where rn = 1;

alter table players rename to players_tmp2;

alter table players_tmp rename to players;
```

If you have a concern about which id will be deleted then you can edit window function.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2f51a117a5f4c1d777f69788b51a46d6)

Comment: Your solution worked great. It only took 4min